# Is it possible to add a third dummy variable using ifelse() in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grouping, dummy-variable

I was using this code to create a new Group column based on partial strings found inside the column var for 2 groups, `Sui` and `Swe`. I had to add another group, `TRD`, and I've been trying to tweak the `ifelse` function do this, but no success. Is this doable? are there any other solutions or other functions that might help me do this?

```
m.df <- molten.df%>% mutate(
Group = ifelse(str_detect(variable, "Sui"), "Sui", "Swedish"))

Current m.df: 
                          var      value    
  ADHD_iFullSuiTrim.Threshold1 0.00549427     
  ADHD_iFullSuiTrim.Threshold1 0.00513955     
  ADHD_iFullSweTrim.Threshold1 0.00466352   
  ADHD_iFullSweTrim.Threshold1 0.00491633   
  ADHD_iFullTRDTrim.Threshold1 0.00658535    
  ADHD_iFullTRDTrim.Threshold1 0.00609122    


Desired Result:
                          var      value    Group
   ADHD_iFullSuiTrim.Threshold1 0.00549427    Sui  
   ADHD_iFullSuiTrim.Threshold1 0.00513955    Sui  
   ADHD_iFullSweTrim.Threshold1 0.00466352   Swedish
   ADHD_iFullSweTrim.Threshold1 0.00491633   Swedish
   ADHD_iFullTRDTrim.Threshold1 0.00658535    TRD
   ADHD_iFullTRDTrim.Threshold1 0.00609122    TRD
```

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated even if the result can be accomplished using other functions.

Comment: Seems like a situation where `case_when` might be useful.

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of your data frame and your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No `ifelse()` is needed. I'd use `Group = str_extract(var, pattern = "(Sui)|(TRD)|(Swe)")`.

You could do fancier regex with a lookbehind for "iFull" and a lookahead for "Trim", but I can never remember how to do that.

A little more roundabout, but general if you want whatever is between "iFull" and "Trim" would be a replacement:

```
str_replace_all(var, pattern = "(.*iFull)|(Trim.*)", "")
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to use multiple `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

m.df <- molten.df %>% 
  mutate(Group = ifelse(str_detect(var, "Sui"), "Sui", 
                        ifelse(str_detect(var, "Swe"), "Swedish", "TRD")))
```

Or `case_when`

```
m.df <- molten.df %>% 
  mutate(Group = case_when(
    str_detect(var, "Sui") ~ "Sui",
    str_detect(var, "Swe") ~ "Swe",
    TRUE                   ~ "TRD"
  ))
```

#### Data Preparation

```
molten.df <- read.table(text = "var      value    
  'ADHD_iFullSuiTrim.Threshold1' 0.00549427     
                 'ADHD_iFullSuiTrim.Threshold1' 0.00513955     
                 'ADHD_iFullSweTrim.Threshold1' 0.00466352   
                 'ADHD_iFullSweTrim.Threshold1' 0.00491633   
                 'ADHD_iFullTRDTrim.Threshold1' 0.00658535    
                 'ADHD_iFullTRDTrim.Threshold1' 0.00609122",
                header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 5):

For future reference - provide all the necessary components for repeating the analysis e.g., packages and example data

```
# load ----
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# data ----
 df=data.frame(var=c('ADHD_iFullSuiTrim.Threshold1',
  'ADHD_iFullSuiTrim.Threshold1',
  'ADHD_iFullSweTrim.Threshold1',
  'ADHD_iFullSweTrim.Threshold1',
  'ADHD_iFullTRDTrim.Threshold1', 
  'ADHD_iFullTRDTrim.Threshold1'),
   value = c(0.00549427, 0.00513955, 0.00466352, 0.00491633, 0.00658535, 0.00609122))    

df %>% 
    mutate(Group = case_when(str_detect(var, "Sui")~"Sui",
                                 str_detect(var, "Swe")~"Swedish",
                                 str_detect(var, "TRD")~"TRD"))
```

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful I'm new on here and do not know very well how to format my questions.